# Is there any elegant way to show active hyperlink style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Maybe I've missed something, but I've found that it's quite difficult to show conditional attributes in rails. Many programmers use helper methods to achieve this, but it still seems like a tedious task. I wonder if anyone has an elegant method of achieving this.

To be clear, let's say we have some css component as below (this example comes from a github opensource css framework: https://primer.style/css/components/navigation), So how would I change an `'aria-current': 'page'` attribute?

```
<nav class="UnderlineNav UnderlineNav--right">
  <div class="UnderlineNav-body">
    <a class="UnderlineNav-item" href="#url" aria-current="page">Item 1</a>
    <a class="UnderlineNav-item" href="#url">Item 2</a>
    <a class="UnderlineNav-item" href="#url">Item 3</a>
    <a class="UnderlineNav-item" href="#url">Item 4</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're saying a 'conditional attribute'.  Which I think is something that changed say an active item when the page value changes.  I remember just using javascript to update via class name.  Just set the classname to active and handle styling for active in that class.  If you're talking about how to dynamically set element attributes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Thomas. What I've interpreted is not exact. Thank you for your correcting.

Comment: What exactly is your question my friend?  Were you wanting to know how to dynamically update an attribute on an element?

Comment: Yes, I wanna get an elegant way to add a attribute to dynamically if its condition is true. Though on my case is not same with add a active tag to the class attribute, I think it should have an easy way there.

Comment: I guess you want a completely ruby way to do it...hmm I would say leave front end to front end and back end to back end.  But I suppose you can do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solve it by a helper method as the follow. If you guys have some other simple way, please let me know. Many thanks.

```
def active_header_link(text, slug, options)
    if current_page? slug
      link_to text, slug, {'aria-current': 'page'}.merge(options)
    else
      link_to text, slug, options
    end
  end
```

then, just call it when necessarily like this

```
<%= active_header_link node.name, node_path(node.slug), class: 'UnderlineNav-item' %>
```